# Python Lex-Yacc(PLY): Not recognizing start of line or start of string

Tags: python, regex, tokenize, lexer, ply

I am very new to [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) and a bit more than a beginner to Python. I am trying to play around with [PLY-3.4](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply-3.4.tar.gz) and python 2.7 to learn it. Please see the code below. I am trying to create a token QTAG which is a string made of zero of more whitespaces followed by 'Q' or 'q',  followed by '.' and a positive integer and one or more whitespaces. For example VALID QTAGs are

```
"Q.11 "
"  Q.12 "
"q.13     "
'''
   Q.14 
'''
```

INVALID ones are

```
"asdf Q.15 "
"Q.  15 "
```

Here is my code:

```
import ply.lex as lex

class LqbLexer:
     # List of token names.   This is always required
     tokens =  [
        'QTAG',
        'INT'
        ]


     # Regular expression rules for simple tokens

    def t_QTAG(self,t):
        r'^[ \t]*[Qq]\.[0-9]+\s+'
        t.value = int(t.value.strip()[2:])
        return t

    # A regular expression rule with some action code
    # Note addition of self parameter since we're in a class
    def t_INT(self,t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)   
    return t


    # Define a rule so we can track line numbers
    def t_newline(self,t):
        r'\n+'
        print "Newline found"
        t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

    # A string containing ignored characters (spaces and tabs)
    t_ignore  = ' \t'

    # Error handling rule
    def t_error(self,t):
        print "Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0]
        t.lexer.skip(1)

    # Build the lexer
    def build(self,**kwargs):
        self.lexer = lex.lex(debug=1,module=self, **kwargs)

    # Test its output
    def test(self,data):
        self.lexer.input(data)
        while True:
             tok = self.lexer.token()
             if not tok: break
             print tok

# test it
q = LqbLexer()
q.build()
#VALID inputs
q.test("Q.11 ")
q.test("  Q.12 ")
q.test("q.13     ")
q.test('''
   Q.14 
''')
# INVALID ones are
q.test("asdf Q.15 ")
q.test("Q.  15 ")
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
LexToken(QTAG,11,1,0)
Illegal character 'Q'
Illegal character '.'
LexToken(INT,12,1,4)
LexToken(QTAG,13,1,0)
Newline found
Illegal character 'Q'
Illegal character '.'
LexToken(INT,14,2,6)
Newline found
Illegal character 'a'
Illegal character 's'
Illegal character 'd'
Illegal character 'f'
Illegal character 'Q'
Illegal character '.'
LexToken(INT,15,3,7)
Illegal character 'Q'
Illegal character '.'
LexToken(INT,15,3,4)
```

Notice that only the first and third of the valid inputs are correctly tokenized. I am not able to figure out why my other valid inputs are not being tokenized properly. In the doc string for t_QTAG:

1. Replacing `'^'` with `'\A'` did not work.
2. I tried by removing `'^'` .  Then all the valid inputs get tokenized, but then second 
   invalid input also gets tokenized.

Any help is appreciated in advance!

Thanks

PS: I joined the google-group ply-hack and tried posting there, but I could not post either directly in the forum or through email. I am not sure if the group is active anymore. Prof. Beazley is not responding either. Any ideas?

Comment: Well you are explicitly stating that whitespace should be ignored, through the `t_ignore` flags, but then you need them in your regex. I do believe that the reason your second "bad input" is getting validated is because the t_ignore is consuming the internal whitespace, making it look like Q.15
Could you try setting your T_QTAG regex to this?

[Qq]\.[0-9]+


Also can you check what happens when you remove whitespace from the t_ignore?

Comment: I should mention I've never used PLY, but have used JFLEX/CUP in the past. Also, why the jumping between [ \t] and \s. Note that \s covers: [ \t\n\r\f\v] which means that this regex will consume newlines without letting your newline checker get to them

Comment: Also you said `followed by '.' and a positive integer and zero or more spaces or tab` whereas your regex uses \s+ at the end, indicating you need at least ONE whitespace at the end. Not sure if intentional.

Comment: @Tadgh Re. your first comment: Thanks for `t_ignore` consuming spaces. It is true. @Tadgh Re. your second comment: You are right. The beginning could be just `\s`. @Tadgh Re. your last comment: The regex is correct but my wordings are wrong! It should read: "... followed by '.' and a positive integer and one or more whitespaces,ie, [ \t\n\r\f\v]." With some documentation reading, I found my correct answer and is posted below. Thanks to @Tadgh for the pointers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the answer myself. Posting it so that others may find it useful.

As @Tadgh rightly pointed out `t_ignore = ' \t'` consumes the spaces and tabs and hence I will not be able to match as per above regex for `t_QTAG` and the consequence is that the second valid input is not tokenized. By reading the PLY documentation carefully, I learned that if the ordering of the regex for tokens is to be maintained then  they  have to be defined in a function rather than strings as was done for `t_ignore`. If strings are used then PLY automatically orders them by  longest to shortest length and appends them *after* the functions. Here `t_ignore` is special, I guess, that it is somehow executed before anything else. This part is not clearly documented. The work around for this to define a function with a new token, eg, `t_SPACETAB`,   *after* `t_QTAG` and just do not return anything. With this, all the *valid* inputs are correctly tokenized now, except the one with triple quotes (the multi-line string containing `"Q.14"`). Also, the invalid ones are, as per specification, not tokenized.

Multi-line string problem: It turns out that internally PLY uses `re` module. In that module, `^` is interpreted only at the beginning of a *string* and NOT beginning of *every line*, by default. To change that behavior, I need to turn on the multi-line flag, which can be done within the regex using `(?m)`. So, to process all the valid and invalid strings in my test properly, the correct regex is:

`r'(?m)^\s*[Qq]\.[0-9]+\s+'`

Here is the corrected code with some more tests added:

```
import ply.lex as lex

class LqbLexer:
    # List of token names.   This is always required

    tokens = [
        'QTAG',
        'INT',
        'SPACETAB'
        ]


    # Regular expression rules for simple tokens

    def t_QTAG(self,t):
        # corrected regex
        r'(?m)^\s*[Qq]\.[0-9]+\s+'
        t.value = int(t.value.strip()[2:])
        return t

    # A regular expression rule with some action code
    # Note addition of self parameter since we're in a class
    def t_INT(self,t):
        r'\d+'
        t.value = int(t.value)    
        return t

    # Define a rule so we can track line numbers
    def t_newline(self,t):
        r'\n+'
        print "Newline found"
        t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

    # A string containing ignored characters (spaces and tabs)
    # Instead of t_ignore  = ' \t'
    def t_SPACETAB(self,t):
        r'[ \t]+'
        print "Space(s) and/or tab(s)"

    # Error handling rule
    def t_error(self,t):
        print "Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0]
        t.lexer.skip(1)

    # Build the lexer
    def build(self,**kwargs):
        self.lexer = lex.lex(debug=1,module=self, **kwargs)

    # Test its output
    def test(self,data):
        self.lexer.input(data)
        while True:
             tok = self.lexer.token()
             if not tok: break
             print tok

# test it
q = LqbLexer()
q.build()
print "-============Testing some VALID inputs===========-"
q.test("Q.11 ")
q.test("  Q.12 ")
q.test("q.13     ")
q.test("""


   Q.14
""")
q.test("""

qewr
dhdhg
dfhg
   Q.15 asda

""")

# INVALID ones are
print "-============Testing some INVALID inputs===========-"
q.test("asdf Q.16 ")
q.test("Q.  17 ")
```

Here is the output:

```
-============Testing some VALID inputs===========-
LexToken(QTAG,11,1,0)
LexToken(QTAG,12,1,0)
LexToken(QTAG,13,1,0)
LexToken(QTAG,14,1,0)
Newline found
Illegal character 'q'
Illegal character 'e'
Illegal character 'w'
Illegal character 'r'
Newline found
Illegal character 'd'
Illegal character 'h'
Illegal character 'd'
Illegal character 'h'
Illegal character 'g'
Newline found
Illegal character 'd'
Illegal character 'f'
Illegal character 'h'
Illegal character 'g'
Newline found
LexToken(QTAG,15,6,18)
Illegal character 'a'
Illegal character 's'
Illegal character 'd'
Illegal character 'a'
Newline found
-============Testing some INVALID inputs===========-
Illegal character 'a'
Illegal character 's'
Illegal character 'd'
Illegal character 'f'
Space(s) and/or tab(s)
Illegal character 'Q'
Illegal character '.'
LexToken(INT,16,8,7)
Space(s) and/or tab(s)
Illegal character 'Q'
Illegal character '.'
Space(s) and/or tab(s)
LexToken(INT,17,8,4)
Space(s) and/or tab(s)
```

Comment: "^ is interpreted only at the beginning of a string and NOT beginning of every line" - this was messing with me! Nice work figuring it out!